# DevExpress custom skins not reflected

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I developed a custom skin using DevExpress Skin Editor and exported it as an assembly. I have included the code below to register the skin and enable it in my application's init method :

```
 
 DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.Default.RegisterAssembly(GetType(DevExpress.UserSkins.customtheme).Assembly)
 DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins()
 CSGuiLib.LookAndFeelManager.SetSkin(GetType(DevExpress.UserSkins.customtheme).Assembly, "customtheme")
```

this theme should make the form windows look something like
[image]

But instead it looks something like this

[image]

I have looked up the documentation and this is all that should be needed. I also verified that there are no global skin settings that are overwriting my skin. Is there somewhere else that the skin needs to be registered?